# Temporarily disable SSH for all users except one and print a banner

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am planing to upgrade a server that have some SSH and rsync(over ssh) users. During this time that I am upgrading the server I don't want anyone else to login to the server.

Is there a way for me to block all SSH logins except for the user "nisse", and print a banner to the other users informing them of the temporary block because of upgrade?

My first plan was to change the default banner and then just remove the users from "AllowUsers" but I was thinking if there is a better way?

Comment: Why do you wish not to block the user `nisse`?  It's this requirement that makes an answer difficult.

Comment: This seems just like the perfect use case for AllowUsers/AllowGroups. What benefits are you hoping to find by taking another route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of any reply to the above queries, I'll have to make an assumption: specifically, that you wish to continue to allow the `nisse` user to log in to assist with the `rsync`.

This is the requirement that's complicating your usage case, and it's indicative of a poor requirement.  The usual method of stopping further users from logging in is to touch `/etc/nologin`; in addition, anything you put into that file will be printed as a rejection banner.  This will stop connections via `ssh`, `sftp`, and `rsync -e ssh`.  It won't log out any current users, so if you're worried about nisse being thrown off before launching the `rsync`, don't be.  `rm /etc/nologin` once you're done.

If the issue is that `nisse` must log in after the ban is in place, as part of the `rsync`, you're doing the `rsync` backwards.  Log in, create `/etc/nologin`, then use `rsync` to push from the current server, instead of pulling from the new one.

If there is some other business-critical reason for `nisse`'s exception that I haven't covered, then andol is right when (s)he points out above that modifying your current `AllowUsers` settings is pretty much the perfect way to achieve the granularity you require.  While you're there, you can further modify your `sshd_config` to use `Banner` to print a banner before rejection, and `nisse` can be told to ignore it.

Comment: `nisse` is my admin(su) user that I will be using to access the server during the upgrade. The problem is that I want to block all other users to use SSH except my self because I will do the server upgrade via SSH. 
I didn't know about the nologin file, I will read up on it.

Comment: As long as you're logged in before you put that file in place - and how else would you put it there? - it will have no effect on your current login.